# Why is my smart object not displaying the image I'm adding?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, smartobject

In a mockup, when I click the Edit smart object layer to add an image to a smart object and I press save, it doesn’t show my logo on the PSD tab with the smart object. What is going on?

Comment: Maybe that smart object isn't connected to the smart object that shows the graphic. If you close the smart object contents and go back to edit it, is your logo still there? If so then the smart object works as it should, just not how the mockup creator intended.

Comment: `This has nothing to do with the issue:` I've made a script that helps with batch processing mockups, especially if you have multiple mockup files to process and/or they have multiple smart objects to replace: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Batch-Mockup-Smart-Object-Replacement-photoshop-script

Answer (score 0):

Possible/related issue: Your smart object file is unlinked from main file, for example by doing *Undo* in your main PSD file.

Suppose you've a file `a.psd` and your logo is a circle shape with red color. You convert it into smart object and save `a.psd` file. A few seconds later, you want to change color to blue, so you double click smart object layer and it opens the logo shape layer in a new tab. Photoshop gives this file a temporary name e.g. `Ellipse 1.psb`. You save it and go back to `a.psd` and notice that color is changed as expected, but you Undo the change and save `a.psd` again. But a few seconds later you realize you need blue really. So you go back to `Ellipse 1.psb` and save it again but it doesn't affect the color in `a.psd` as it unlinks it.

You need to double click again the smart object layer in `a.psd`.